# How to parse this json getting in the response

Tags: php, json, laravel

i know this is invalid json but i am getting this json in response from creditswitch api i cannot change this response but i want to parse this json
when i replace this just details key like

```
desired json response
{
    "statusCode": "00",
    "statusDescription": {
        "customerNo": 283375350,
        "accountStatus": "OPEN",
        "firstname": "ADVENTURE",
        "lastname": "MOBILE",
        "customerType": "SUD",
        "invoicePeriod": 1,
        "dueDate": "2018-09-29T00:00:00+01:00"
    }
}
```

i get valid json but how to remove that 1st part of json i dont know any solution over it following is the original json i am getting.

```
this is the original json response
{
    "details": {
        "number": "10553886499",
        "requestType": "VALIDATE_DEVICE_NUMBER"
    },
    "serviceId": "AQA"
} 
{
    "statusCode": "00",
    "statusDescription": {
        "customerNo": 283375350,
        "accountStatus": "OPEN",
        "firstname": "ADVENTURE",
        "lastname": "MOBILE",
        "customerType": "SUD",
        "invoicePeriod": 1,
        "dueDate": "2018-09-29T00:00:00+01:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: Would a simple detection like this work? `$validJsonParts = explode("}\n{",$invalidJson);`?

Comment: "_i know this is invalid json_" Where?

Comment: **Your question is not clear!!** Which JSON do you get from the API? Then tell us what you want to convert it into

Comment: @kerbholz The second bit of JSON is not valid, its missing a `,` between objects

Comment: please see updated question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ah, right, the wording made me think the first one was invalid. Thx

Comment: Seeing that all fields are unique, a simpler extraction rather than parsing/traversing would be feasible: preg_match_all for `"(\w+)":, "?([^"\s]+)"?` and array_combine.

Comment: _SIDE NOTE_ You really ought to report this issue with the JSON to `creditswitch`

Comment: @RiggsFolly u r right what i have in mind that we can replace 1st object or we can add simple comma at the end of 1st object

Comment: The problem with frigging the data is that if the data changes shape for any reason your fiddle will likely cause issues later on.

Comment: i dont think data will change in future

Comment: Are you sure its not your code that is causing the issue. Is this JSON received from ONE request/response interaction with the API or do you build this from more than one interaction

Comment: yes i have posted the original json response

Comment: looks like, concated two response json, please verify that this json is actually you receive

Comment: please add `var_dump` on the variable you are logging the output from. Also the call to the API and subsequent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, obviously this API is outputting two json objects at a time, which isn't standard, and confuses php json decoder. I think you could do something clever with `preg_match` to split, though it's quite complicated with subsequences. I have created this little routine that seems to work at splitting these into parts that are decodable

```
$input=<<<DAT
{
    "details": {
        "number": "10553886499",
        "requestType": "VALIDATE_DEVICE_NUMBER"
    },
    "serviceId": "AQA"
} 
{
    "statusCode": "00",
    "statusDescription": {
        "customerNo": 283375350,
        "accountStatus": "OPEN",
        "firstname": "ADVENTURE",
        "lastname": "MOBILE",
        "customerType": "SUD",
        "invoicePeriod": 1,
        "dueDate": "2018-09-29T00:00:00+01:00"
    }
}
DAT;

$cur_json='';
$requests=[];
$inbrace=false;
$inquotes=false;
$inescape=false;
$bracecnt=0;
for($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($input);$i++){
    $c=mb_substr($input,$i,1);
    switch($c){
        case '{':
            if(!$inbrace)
                $inbrace=true;
            $bracecnt++;
            $cur_json.=$c;
            break;
        case '}':
            if($inquotes)
                $cur_json.=$c;
            else{
                $bracecnt--;
                $cur_json.=$c;
                if($bracecnt==0)
                {
                    $inbrace=false;
                    $requests[]=$cur_json;
                    $cur_json='';
                }
            }
            break;
        case '"':
            $cur_json.=$c;
            if(!$inescape&&$inquotes)
                $inquotes=false;
            else
                $inquotes=true;
            break;
        case '\\':
            $cur_json.=$c;
            if(!$inescape)
                $inescape=true;
            else
                $inescape=false;
            break;
        default:
            $cur_json.=$c;
            break;
    }
}
$requests[]=$cur_json;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(json_decode($requests[0]));
var_dump(json_decode($requests[1]));
```

Comment: i dont get <<<DAT

Comment: Yes, input is string. <<<DAT is heredoc syntax I used just for example, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php